# Responsive Bootstrap-4 grid system not collapsing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to break the grid into 1 image per row in `sm`.

This is my first trial with bootstrap 4, I went over the grid system there and it stated that reponsive breaks occur when suffixing a size to each `col-` Yet I can't see any breakage.

### From large screen:

[image]

### To smaller screen:

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid text-right">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-img"
                     style="background-image:url(https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                    <h4 class="card-title">das das</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">lorem oirrwerwer asdf asfd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-img"
                     style="background-image:url(https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                    <h4 class="card-title">das das</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">lorem oirrwerwer asdf asfd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity:1;
}
.card:hover .card-img,
.card:focus .card-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity:0.5;
}

.card:hover .card-img-overlay{
  color:#730d0d;
}

.card-img-overlay>h4, .card-img-overlay>p{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.card-img-overlay:hover h4, .card-img-overlay:hover p{
  visibility: visible;
}

.card:hover .card-img-overlay p{

}
```

Comment: Check if you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` in your `head` tag

Comment: put it in as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is the lack of

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

in the `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Good eye by Michał Drabik in his answer. That is precisely the problem. When I pasted your code into a new Bootstrap project, the viewport meta was already pre-populated so I didn't even notice.

**ORIGINAL:**

Perhaps try testing it in browser to make sure. I copied and pasted your code unaltered into a brand new bootstrap environment in Dreamweaver and it behaved exactly as desired, both in the native live view and in several different browser tests. I don't see any problems with the code itself.

The only other thing I can think of is that your Bootstrap framework is somehow corrupted (you *are* designing within the bootstrap framework, right?) Without seeing the associated .css and .js files it would be hard to give you much more help. Maybe try starting up a fresh Bootstrap project from scratch and paste the above code in there and see if you still have issues. If you don't and it works, you probably screwed something up in the original framework.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `col-12`, not `col-xs/sm-12`.

`col-xs/sm-12` doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4. - EDIT... It does, I'm incorrect.

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity:1;
}
.card:hover .card-img,
.card:focus .card-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity:0.5;
}

.card:hover .card-img-overlay{
  color:#730d0d;
}

.card-img-overlay>h4, .card-img-overlay>p{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.card-img-overlay:hover h4, .card-img-overlay:hover p{
  visibility: visible;
}

.card:hover .card-img-overlay p{

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div class="container-fluid text-right">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-img"
                     style="background-image:url(https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                    <h4 class="card-title">das das</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">lorem oirrwerwer asdf asfd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-img"
                     style="background-image:url(https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                    <h4 class="card-title">das das</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">lorem oirrwerwer asdf asfd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-sm` exist in Bootstrap 4, as explained [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Comment: Still works when you remove col-sm as you can see in my code above. In this situation, OP shouldn't be using col-sm IMO.